# "Could not execute method of the activity" while call the list getter of adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, custom-adapter

I bind ListView with multiple rows select function. I bind the list view with custom adapter. But problem while I want to get the list from Adapter an error is shown - "Could not execute method of the activity". I also set the getter property in the adapter. But while I call the getter method it throw error.

Please suggest some solution so that I can solve it.

Adapter:

```
public class CityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public List<CityModle.City> citys;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private CitySelectInterface listener;
    private ArrayList<CityModle.City> arraylist;

    public List<CityModle.City> getCitys() {
        return citys;
    }

    public CityAdapter(Context context, List<CityModle.City> citys, CitySelectInterface listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.citys = citys;
        this.listener = listener;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<CityModle.City>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(citys);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("getCountJit",this.citys.size()+"") ;
        return this.citys.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CityModle.City getItem(int i) {
        return this.citys.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cityrowlayout, parent, false);
            mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(this.citys.get(position).getName());
        if(this.citys.get(position).isCheckBox() == true)
        {
            mViewHolder.imageCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mViewHolder.imageCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mViewHolder.imageCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(context, "testClick"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                listener.cityTableRowClick(String.valueOf(position));


                int setView = 0;boolean setchk=false;
                if(mViewHolder.imageCheck.getVisibility()== View.GONE) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "GONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mViewHolder.imageCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    setchk = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "VISIBLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mViewHolder.imageCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    setchk = false;
                }

                citys.get(position).setCheckBox(setchk);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        citys.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            citys.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (CityModle.City wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    citys.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private class MyViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView imageCheck;
        public MyViewHolder(View item) {
            tvTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.nameOfCountry);
            imageCheck = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.imageCheck);
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity:

```
public void closerlviewpopup(View view) {
    List<CityModle.City> cts = cityAdapter.getCitys();
    Toast.makeText(this, cts.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //cts.size() throws an error Could not execute method of the activity
}
```

Error:

```
05-08 17:57:12.359 15243-15243/com.burhanrashid52.imageeditor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.burhanrashid52.imageeditor, PID: 15243
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4028)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:928)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:723)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4023)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:928) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:723) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x64
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:318)
    at android.content.res.VivoResources.getText(VivoResources.java:123)
    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:307)
    at com.burhanrashid52.imageeditor.SetUpActivity.closerlviewpopup(SetUpActivity.java:225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4023) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5425) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:928) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:723)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String
>   resource ID #0x64

Indicates problem with some String resource which you did not provide. `cts.size()` is returning `int` where the `Toast.makeText` function requires a String. You need to change the line as follows.

```
Toast.makeText(this, cts.size().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```